# Unable to log in to phpMyAdmin 5.1 using cookie authentication

Tags: linux, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Running phpMyAdmin v. 5.0.2 and it works fine.

Downloaded [5.1.0-rc1](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/5.1.0-rc1/), unzipped it to public_html and added server by phpMyAdmin/setup.

Also tried to manually edit the configuration.

When I try to log in by password I only get routed back to the log in page. No errors.

More specifically:

1. `http://localhost/~user/phpMyAdmin/index.php`
2. Enter credentials
3. `http://localhost/~user/phpMyAdmin/index.php?route=/&route=%2F&lang=en`

Apache logs show a 302, so not sure if that is a clue:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021:04:45:55 +0100] "POST /~user/phpMyAdmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 1554 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021:04:45:55 +0100] "GET /~user/phpMyAdmin/index.php?route=/&route=%2F&lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 6295 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
```

Nothing in MySQL logs.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

---

v5.0.2 config.inc.php:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '.KmeninsAmd6354s^asdk?\'=DEfaeafakm7as';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

v5.1.0-rc1 config.inc.php:

```
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';


$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '.KmeninsAmd6354s^asdk?\'=DEfaeafakm7as';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

---

Using `auth_type` `http` and `config` works fine.

Comment: In most cases `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are treated as separate hosts. Be sure phpMyAdmin and Apache are configured on the same host (i.e. 127.0.0.1 or localhost).  You should make sure the phpMyAdmin database was actually created when you ran the setup.  We are going to need more details. You can provide those details by performing an [edit] to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks. I use localhost in configuration for phpMyAdmin. Have looked around but fail at finding how to see if Apache is configured for localhost or IP – hence not sure what information to update Q with. It is mostly defaults, i.e. ports.conf is `Listen 80`. Is that it? I did not create any phpMyAdmin database in setup. Only added a new server (localhost) with default settings and proceeded with download. And the v5.0.2 still works fine with the same connection specs.

Comment: You obviously can’t use defaults, you have to customize the install, so it can communicate with the database.  Whenever, I upgraded phpMyAdmin in the past I replaced everything but the configuration file, then I ran the setup to perform the upgrade.

Comment: The phpMyAdmin documentation is extremely detailed.  You provided us nearly no information about your server configuration.  Honestly, you need a discussion forum, not a Q&A website like Super User